# How to convert regex match.Value to integer?

Tags: c#, regex

```
List<int> ids = ExtractIds("United Kingdom (656) - Aberdeen (7707)");
```

The above list should be populated by the method below, which strips the values from within parenthesis.

If I use match.Value as a string and assign it to List< string > it seems to work ok. But when I try to convert it to an integer I get the error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

What am I doing wrong?

```
public List<int> ExtractIds(string str)
{
    MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(str, @"\((.*?)\)");
    List<int> ExtractedIds = new List<int>();
    foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
    {
        int theid = int.Parse(match.Value);
        ExtractedIds.Add(theid);
    }

    return ExtractedIds;
}
```

Comment: in other languages the 0th match represents the full match string...  Not positive about c#, but seems like a good place to look

Comment: You're matching anything in parenthesis - you probably want `\d+` instead of `.*?`.

Comment: You are not using the debugger. Find out what match.Value *is* and you will know what went wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `match.Groups[1].Value` instead of `match.Value` to just get the string found inside the brackets - i.e. not including the brackets themselves.

Use `\d*?` instead of `.?*` to ensure you're only matching digits, not anything in brackets!

Then you don't even need the `?` any more because `\d` doesn't match a closing bracket.

Instead of switching to look in `Groups[1]`, you can use *lookarounds* in a regular expression such as

```
(?<=\()\d(?=\))
```

to make sure `Match` only contains the digits themselves.

Comment: Alternatively you can use named capture groups instead of integer indexed groups - keep in mind `match.Groups[2]` or more may also exist, as well as no matches at all. Your code should take this into consideration.

Comment: Yup - with a simple regex like this I wouldn't worry too much, but anything more complicated and I'd consider naming the capture.

Comment: A big thank you to everyone for the informative answers and examples - all good now and with some valuable improvements.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your code, you are getting match.Value includes the brackets around the number, this will obviously throw exception.

rewrite you pattern as @"(\d)+" this will group your number but ignore the brackets.

```
public List<int> ExtractIds(string str)
{
     MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(str, @"(\d)+");
     List<int> ExtractedIds = new List<int>();
     foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
     {
         int theid = int.Parse(match.Value);
         ExtractedIds.Add(theid);
      }
      return ExtractedIds;
 }
```

Hope this helps.